# Identity that arises from 2 solutions to the problem of the points

Tags: probability

Problem of the points: Bernoulli trials result in a success with probability $p$ and failure with probability $1-p$. What is the probability that $n$ successes occur before $m$ failures?

Solution 1 (due to Fermat): In order for $n$ successes to occur before $m$ failures, it is necessary and sufficient that there be at least $n$ successes in the first $m+n-1$ trials. Then, there are $(m+n-1)-n=m-1$ failures, so $n$ successes indeed occur before $m$ failures. On the other hand, if $k<n$ successes occur, $(m+n-1)-k>m$ failures occur, so $m$ failures occur before $n$ successes. Thus, applying binomial probability we get

$$\sum_{k=n}^{m+n-1} \binom{n+m-1}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{m+n-1-k}$$

for our probability.

Solution 2: The probability that it takes exactly $k$ trials to get $n$ successes is

$$\binom{k-1}{n-1}p^{n}(1-p)^{k-n}$$

(The first $k-1$ trials must contain $n-1$ successes and the $k$th trial must be a success for $k$ trials to be exactly enough to get to $n$ successes.) It must take at most $n+m-1$ trials to get to $n$ successes in order for there to be less than $m$ failures before the $n$th success. Hence, the probability is

$$\sum_{k=n}^{m+n-1}\binom{k-1}{n-1}p^{n}(1-p)^{k-n}$$

I am wondering, **how can I show algebraically that these 2 are the same?** That is,

$$\sum_{k=n}^{m+n-1}\binom{k-1}{n-1}p^{n}(1-p)^{k-n}=\sum_{k=n}^{m+n-1} \binom{n+m-1}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{m+n-1-k}$$